# Group UIButtons to limit "selected" state

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have a row of 5 buttons, of which only one button should be "selected" at once. I call

```
[button setSelected:YES]
```

triggered by the corresponding IBAction to set the state of a touched button to "selected".

Is it possible to create some sort of **button group** where only the latest touched button of the row shows as selected and all others switch back to their "default" state? (kind of like radio buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to create some sort of button group where only the
>   latest touched button of the row shows as selected and all others
>   switch back to their "default" state? (kind of like radio buttons)

So radiobuttons then?  A nice implementation called [MNMRadioGroup](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mnmradiogroup) does exactly that.

However, iOS also includes the native [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) object which only allows one section to be selected at a time.